# How do I add a blank row for a multi value IMPORTXML function?

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**This is my importxml:**

```
=IMPORTXML(CA1,"//div[@class='1a']/div[@class='1b']/div[@class='1c']/img[@class='1d']/@src 
| //div[@class='2a']/span[@class='2b'] 
| //div[@class='3a']/span[@class='3b'] 
| //div[@class='4a']/span[@class='4b'] 
| //div[@class='5a']/span[@class='5b'] 
| //div[@class='6a']/span[6] 
| //div[@class='7a']/span[8] 
| //a/@title")
```

**it displays something like this:**

img src
span1
span2
span3
span4
span5
span6
a title7

Now sometimes, one of the spans or the img is missing.

So It would just make 7 or 6 or 5 etc... rows and only show the values that it finds.

Instead of eliminating the row, would it be possible to add a blank row?

**For example:**

img src
span1
BLANK ROW
span3
span4
BLANK ROW
span6
a title7

**Instead of:**

img src
span1
span3
span4
span6
a title7

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution you can do is separate the single `IMPORTXML` into multiple `IMPORTXML` commands and then have `IFERROR` added. Combining it into one will prevent you from substituting every non-matching pattern which yields into nothing.

#### Formula:

```
=IFERROR(CA1,"//div[@class='1a']/div[@class='1b']/div[@class='1c']/img[@class='1d']/@src]"), "BLANK ROW")
=IFERROR(CA1,"//div[@class='2a']/span[@class='2b']"), "BLANK ROW")
...
=IFERROR(CA1,"//div[@class='7a']/span[8]"), "BLANK ROW")
=IFERROR(CA1,"//a/@title"), "BLANK ROW")
```

#### Sample:

[image: sample]
`=IMPORTXML("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=EUR&date=2020-10-31","(//h2[@class='heading__Heading1-n07sti-0 heading__Heading2-n07sti-1 iXbZUl'])[1] | (//h2[@class='heading__Heading1-n07sti-0 heading__Heading2-n07sti-1 iXbZUl'])[2] | (//h2[@class='heading__Heading1-n07sti-0 heading__Heading2-n07sti-1 iXbZUl'])[3] | (//h2[@class='heading__Heading1-n07sti-0 heading__Heading2-n07sti-1 iXbZUl'])[4]")`

#### Output:

[image: output]

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=EUR&date=2020-10-31","(//h2[@class='heading__Heading1-n07sti-0 heading__Heading2-n07sti-1 iXbZUl'])[1]"), "BLANK ROW")
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=EUR&date=2020-10-31","(//h2[@class='heading__Heading1-n07sti-0 heading__Heading2-n07sti-1 iXbZUl'])[2]"), "BLANK ROW")
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=EUR&date=2020-10-31","(//h2[@class='heading__Heading1-n07sti-0 heading__Heading2-n07sti-1 iXbZUl'])[3]"), "BLANK ROW")
=IFERROR(IMPORTXML("https://www.xe.com/currencytables/?from=EUR&date=2020-10-31","(//h2[@class='heading__Heading1-n07sti-0 heading__Heading2-n07sti-1 iXbZUl'])[4]"), "BLANK ROW")
```

Comment: I am unable to break down the importxml because it's dynamically changing content, the only way I can match it is by capturing the whole section at once. Is there a way to do something like this: `=IFERROR(IMPORTXML(CA1,"//div[@class='1a']/div[@class='1b']/div[@class='1c']/img[@class='1d']/@src | //div[@class='2a']/span[@class='2b'] | //div[@class='3a']/span[@class='3b'] | //div[@class='4a']/span[@class='4b'] | //div[@class='5a']/span[@class='5b'] | //div[@class='6a']/span[6] | //div[@class='7a']/span[8] | //a/@title", "BLANK ROW")`

Comment: Hi @chaimsem, the problem is that `IMPORTXML` returns the value as an array and skips the xpaths with no matches. The only way is to separate them. If the content changes and the one xpath is now not found/existing, then it will just return `#N/A`, and wrapping it with `IFERROR` will change the value to "BLANK ROW". Have you tried separating it?

Comment: Can you try share the url, xpaths and the actual values you want to have if that's fine? I'll try and have it work on my side. or share a duplicate of the sheet you are working on. @chaimsem

Comment: I did, on the importxml it returns one set of values in a row just like I have with my code but it does it only once, meaning only 1 set of 8 rows. And beside it the iferror function does the same thing but because it's calling one item at a time and the page is on refresh the things don't match. I wish I could replicate this but it's sensitive info.

Comment: I'm sorry. as what you wanted on the first comment, it can't be done (as far as I know). Maybe you can try other way to fetching the data. Have you tried apps script? Apps Script is very powerful so it might be better to use it. If you can do an apps script solution, I'll try and provide you with one (but it won't be using xpath, but html tags, you will need to use another set of parameters instead of xpath for [`UrlFetchApp.fetch`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)). @chaimsem

Comment: i figured out the problem. the site is dynamically changing. Now it's not. So I can pull the stuff in order. The problem is that when the div, span etc... is empty. Meaning it's there but with no text inside. The importxml skips and puts the next in the same cell. I need it to not skip and keep the cell blank. Any idea? I made a question for this here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400628/how-to-leave-a-blank-cell-and-not-skip-it-with-importxml