# How to leave a blank cell and not skip it with Importxml?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Basically I have an import xml code:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.example.com/listings.php?","//*[@id='listings']//*[@class='address']")
```

and it spits out the value in a row.

However if the text within the (div/span) class is empty it just skips over it and shows the next one in the cell below.

I don't want it to skip over blank text if the div with that class exists, even if it has no text inside. But rather create a blank cell so it doesn't mess with the values of the column beside it.

How is this possible?

Comment: I am afraid there's no simple solution. Please provide a real URL and let us see the exact problem. I think there's workaround adding one more value to your importxml that is present in all divs (number of entry for example). This way you can make double or triple import importxml(url,"xpath1|xpath2|xpath3") and then try to solve the problem in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

So if this is your own site, the only solution I found was to add `&nbsp;` into all the empty divs/spans or w.e

This worked for me and left a blank cell which matched the column beside it.

Just keep in mind that if your content is dynamically refreshing or changing, you'll need to create a param to not change the content, otherwise it won't match the columns, even though you have the white space.